# calculate average over multiple data frames

Tags: r

I would like to use R for plotting performance evaluation results of distinct DB systems. For each system I loaded the same data and execute the same queries in several iterations.

The data for a single systems looks like this:

```
"iteration", "lines", "loadTime", "query1", "query2", "query3"
1, 100000, 120.4, 0.5, 6.4, 1.2
1, 100000, 110.1, 0.1, 5.2, 2.1
1, 50000, 130.3, 0.2, 4.3, 2.2

2, 100000, 120.4, 0.1, 2.4, 1.2
2, 100000, 300.2, 0.2, 4.5, 1.4
2, 50000, 235.3, 0.4, 4.2, 0.5

3, 100000, 233.5, 0.7, 8.3, 6.7
3, 100000, 300.1, 0.9, 0.5, 4.4
3, 50000, 100.2, 0.4, 9.2, 1.2
```

What I need now (for plotting) is a matrix or data frame containing the average of these measurements.

At the moment I am doing this:

```
# read the file
all_results <- read.csv(file="file.csv", head=TRUE, sep=",")

# split the results by iteration
results <- split(all_results, all_results$iteration)

# convert each result into a data frane
r1 = as.data.frame(results[1])
r2 = as.data.frame(results[2])
r3 = as.data.frame(results[3])

# calculate the average
(r1 + r2 +r3) / 3
```

I could put all this into a function and calculate the average matrix in a for loop, but I have the vague feeling that there must be a more elegant solution. Any ideas?

What can I do for cases when I have incomplete results, e.g., when one iteration has less rows than the others?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, on a given DB system, in each "iteration" (1...N) you are loading a sequence of DataSets (1,2,3) and running queries on them. It seems like at the end you want to calculate the average time across all iterations, **for each DataSet**. If so, you actually need to have an additional column `DataSet` in your `all_results` table that identifies the DataSet. We can add this column as follows:

```
all_results <- cbind( data.frame( DataSet = rep(1:3,3) ), all_results )
> all_results
  DataSet iteration  lines loadTime query1 query2 query3
1       1         1 100000    120.4    0.5    6.4    1.2
2       2         1 100000    110.1    0.1    5.2    2.1
3       3         1  50000    130.3    0.2    4.3    2.2
4       1         2 100000    120.4    0.1    2.4    1.2
5       2         2 100000    300.2    0.2    4.5    1.4
6       3         2  50000    235.3    0.4    4.2    0.5
7       1         3 100000    233.5    0.7    8.3    6.7
8       2         3 100000    300.1    0.9    0.5    4.4
9       3         3  50000    100.2    0.4    9.2    1.2
```

Now you can use the `ddply` function from the `plyr` package to easily extract the averages for the load and query times for each DataSet.

```
> ddply(all_results, .(DataSet), colwise(mean, .(loadTime, query1, query2)))
  DataSet loadTime    query1 query2
1       1 158.1000 0.4333333    5.7
2       2 236.8000 0.4000000    3.4
3       3 155.2667 0.3333333    5.9
```

Incidentally, I highly recommend you look at Hadley Wickham's [`plyr` package](http://had.co.nz/plyr/plyr-intro-090510.pdf) for a rich set of data-manipulation functions

Comment: that's indeed more elegant than for loops...thanks for the hint.

Comment: what if I want to include the "lines" column in the output frame of ddply? I could do that by simply calculating the mean also over the lines; but this somehow doesn't make sense since the line numbers are static values;

Comment: I see what you mean, but I suppose there's no harm in taking the "mean" of a bunch of identical values!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why you need to split `all_results` by `iteration`.  You can just use `aggregate` on `all_results`.  There's no need for all iterations to have the same number of observations.

```
Lines <- "iteration, lines, loadTime, query1, query2, query3
1, 100000, 120.4, 0.5, 6.4, 1.2
1, 100000, 110.1, 0.1, 5.2, 2.1
1, 50000, 130.3, 0.2, 4.3, 2.2
2, 100000, 120.4, 0.1, 2.4, 1.2
2, 100000, 300.2, 0.2, 4.5, 1.4
2, 50000, 235.3, 0.4, 4.2, 0.5
3, 100000, 233.5, 0.7, 8.3, 6.7
3, 100000, 300.1, 0.9, 0.5, 4.4
3, 50000, 100.2, 0.4, 9.2, 1.2"

all_results <- read.csv(textConnection(Lines))

aggregate(all_results[,-1], by=all_results[,"iteration",drop=FALSE], mean)
```

Comment: I think the OP needs to average by DataSet as I said in my answer, not by "iteration" ( it doesn't make sense to take the average of a dataset that has 100000 lines and one with 50000 lines). At least that's my interpretation of what he really wants to do.

Comment: ... but the idea of using `aggregate` is nice though (+1). I was just trying to use this as an exercise to practice using `plyr`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have something like this in mind?

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(results, mean))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
> Reduce("+", results) / length(results)
  DataSet iteration lines loadTime    query1 query2   query3
1       1         2 1e+05 158.1000 0.4333333    5.7 3.033333
2       2         2 1e+05 236.8000 0.4000000    3.4 2.633333
3       3         2 5e+04 155.2667 0.3333333    5.9 1.300000
```

An `aggregate` solution which also works for the unbalanced case follows.  Assume that the ith row of any iteration is for data set i and that we simply average within datasets.  Using `aggregate` is straight forward. The only tricky part is getting the assignment of rows to data sets correct so that it works in the unbalanced case too.  That is done by the `list(data.set = ...)` expression.

```
> it <- all_results$iteration
> aggregate(all_results, list(data.set = seq_along(it) - match(it, it) + 1), mean)
  data.set iteration lines loadTime    query1 query2   query3
1        1         2 1e+05 158.1000 0.4333333    5.7 3.033333
2        2         2 1e+05 236.8000 0.4000000    3.4 2.633333
3        3         2 5e+04 155.2667 0.3333333    5.9 1.300000
```

Comment: I was thinking of suggesting the same thing, but `+` doesn't work if every `data.frame` isn't the same size.

Comment: The data frames are the same size since the poster indicated that the code he posted does work but its just that he wants something more "elegant".

Comment: @Gabor I was referring to the last sentence in his question.

Comment: OK. I have added a second solution.  One could define a plus function but in this case I think its easier just to use aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

Try, e.g.,

```
with(all_results, tapply(lines, iteration, mean))
```